# C# WPF better way to iterate on children and change property

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, properties, casting

I have to iterate through all children of a stackPanel.
Being new to WPF I do that

```
foreach (var item in spTab3.Children)
  {
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(ListBox))
      ((ListBox)item).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     if (item.GetType() == typeof(Grid))
      ((Grid)item).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ....
  }
```

that is I have to cast all types of elements to get to set the visibility. I bet there is a smarter way to do all the togheter.
Thanks

---EDIT---
So in short I have a stackpanel spTab3 with children.
When I do what suggested by Bijington:

```
spTab3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;<----------set all children to collapsed
spTab3.Children[iVisibleTab-1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;<----set only one to visible
```

the second line has no effect.
While when I do as stated by Spawn that works:

```
foreach (var item in spTab3.Children)
    ((UIElement)item).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

 spTab3.Children[iVisibleTab-1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

can anyone explain me why?!?

Comment: Why do you want to set all visibilities to `Collapsed`?

Comment: Because first I set all them to collapsed and then I set to Visible only the one I'm interested in.

Comment: Visibility property inherits from UIElement, so you need to cast just to UIElement.

Comment: @Spawn thanx a lot!! foreach (UIElement item in spTab3.Children)
        item.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; works. You might want to propose it as a solution so that I can vote you

Comment: Do you have to iterate through all the children and change their visibilities? Could you not just change the visibility of the StackPanel itself?

Comment: @Bijington YES thanx!..... as I said I am new to wpf

Comment: @Patrick spTab3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;<----------set all children to collapsed sorry I don't think I explained this fully. That line does not set all the children to be collapsed, it just sets the StackPanels visibility to Collapsed. If you need to be able to show and hide single children then Spawns solution is the one you need.

Comment: @Bijington fine thank you the same for your efforts.

Comment: @Patrick no problem, if it helps if you want all your controls to be hidden when first showing the UI you can set the Visibility property in the XAML file (assuming you are creating them in XAML). This way you only need to make the items visible without having to loop through all the Children to hide them to start with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every child in Panel is UIElement. So its type derived from DependencyObject which has SetValue method. Use it.

```
foreach (UIElement item in spTab3.Children)
{
    item.SetValue(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed (or Visible));
}
```

Keep in mind that it's not a WPF style solution. You better need to declare dependency property and to bind item's visibility to this property.

In case that panel and code are inside a Window

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsItemVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsItemVisible", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

public Visibility IsItemVisible
{
    get
    {
        return (Visibility)GetValue(IsItemVisibleProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsItemVisibleProperty, value);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Visibility="{Binding IsItemVisible,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">Collapsed 1</Button>
        <Button Visibility="{Binding IsItemVisible,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">Collapsed 2</Button>
        <Button>Visible</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: thank you that's correct but Spawn said it before. I'll wait some more time waiting for his answer before flagging your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way of showing/hiding the `Children` within the `StackPanel` would be to simply set the `Visibility` property on the `StackPanel` itself.

Comment: sorry I unchecked it a solution. The reason is in my edit.